# Getting a attribute from the last tr of a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got stuck a bit in this jquery script.I want to get the `link` attribute of the last `td` in the `tr` on check of the check box.
Here is the HTML

```
      <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="happy"></td>
          <td style="width: 310px; line-height: 14px;" class="fileName <?php echo $myClass; ?>" ><div style="width: 310px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="https://abcd.com/<?php echo $info."/".$myinfo['name'];?>" title="<?php echo $myinfo['name'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $fileName.'.'.$fileExtension; ?></a></div></td>
           <td style="width: 150px;"><?php echo $fileSize; ?> KB</td>
           <td style="width: 150px;"><?php echo $fileModified; ?></td>
           <td style="width: 150px;">
               <a href="javascript:void(0);" ><span id="" link="https://abcd.com/<?php echo $info."/".$myinfo['name'];?>" title="<?php echo $myinfo['name'];?>" class="shareIcon"></span></a>
               <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span id="deleteIcon" link="<?php echo $myBucket['name'];?>" class="deleteIcon"></span></a>
           </td>
         </tr>
```

I want to get each of the link attribute in the last td when more than one checkbox are.
What I tried is this

```
   $("input[name='check']").on('change',function() {
   var checked = $("input[name='check']:checked");
   // console.log(checked);
   $.each(checked,function(){ 
   //console.log(checked.length); 
   if(checked.length>1){
          //  console.log('more than 1');             
          //console.log(checked.parents('td').siblings('.shareIcon'));
          checked.parents('td').siblings('.shareIcon'),function(){
          console.log($(this).attr('link'));

          }      
      } 
   })
 });
```

Comment: for you checked.length = 1.so its not going inside.

Comment: I think that is not the issue as I get the values right over there.The issue I find is to get the link attribute using either the `parent` or `sibling` method

Comment: oops @MohammadAreebSiddiqui tested doesnt make difference

Comment: @KousikChowdhury I have multiple rows and I want it to go inside for more than one as it is for multiple send or delete functionality

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ would be more help full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
 $("input[name='check']").on('change', function () {
     var checked = $("input[name='check']:checked");
     $.each(checked, function () {
         if (checked.length >= 1) {
             $.each(checked.parent().siblings().last().children().children(), function() {
                 console.log($(this).data("link"));
             });
         }
     })
 });
```

And this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="happy">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 310px; line-height: 14px;" class="fileName <?php echo $myClass; ?>">
            <div style="width: 310px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="https://abcd.com/areeb" title="areeb" target="_blank">some_file.php</a>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 150px;">212KB</td>
        <td style="width: 150px;">some_file.php</td>
        <td style="width: 150px;"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span id="" data-link="https://abcd.com/areeb" title="<?php echo $myinfo['name'];?>" class="shareIcon"></span></a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span id="deleteIcon" data-link="<?php echo $myBucket['name'];?>" class="deleteIcon"></span></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[<kbd>Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6rd/)

---

## Code Explanation:

---

### JavaScript Code:

I have just changed you if condition a little bit so that it can match even one element as well. Then the `$.each()` function is also changed a little bit. I am first targetting the parent, `td`, of your checkbox then I am getting all it's siblings then I select the last sibling then I pop in into it's children that are `a` or anchor tags and then I pop into the children of those `a`s aswell that are the `span`s and then for each of the span I log it's `data-link` attribute.

### HTML Code:

I have just changed the name of the `link` attribute to `data-link` attribute for easier access through the `data` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes:
1) Validate your html, improper closing of `input` tag.  This leads the following

```
checked.parent()  //points the body not its actual td
```

2) Proper way of escaping `/` characters.

```
link="https://abcd.com/<?php echo $info."/".$myinfo['name'];?>"  //WRONG
```

3) The below code will point only `td` parent of `input`, so it fails

```
checked.parents('td').find('.shareIcon').attr('link')
```

Finally, there is no need to iterate inorder to get the last `td` you can use `:last` like

```
 $("input[name='check']").on('change',function() {
   var checked = $("input[name='check']:checked");
     console.log(checked.parents('tr')
                           .find('td:last')
                           .find('.shareIcon').attr('link'));
 });
```

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrrHP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = $('input[name="check"]').on('change', function () {
    inputs.each(function () {
        var i = $(this);

        if (i.is(':checked')) {
            console.log(i.closest('tr').find('.shareIcon').attr('link'));
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9zF8/)